# puntos en números mayores de 1000 y con decimales con php

Tags: php

estoy usando echo `number_format("1000,8",2,",","."); y` me arroja 1.000,00.  Lo que quiero es que muestre 1.000,80.  Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se usa el . para separar los decimales, es decir:

```
number_format("1000.8",2,",",".");
```

con esto obtienes la salida:

1.000,80

Answer (score 1):

Te comento lo siguiente en el caso de la función number format

Se compone de las siguientes reglas

> 1. El número que será susceptible de la acción de la función, los miles se separan por comas
> 2. Los decimales de la función number_format se identifican por punto

```
echo number_format("1000.8",2,",",".");
```

**Fuente de consulta**
http://php.net/manual/es/function.number-format.php